# why do odd magic squares have the same rank as their size?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, correlation, matrix-rank, magic-square

why do odd magic squares have the same rank as their size whats special about odd magic squares? and why do even magic squares alternate

The results are below where n is the size and r is the corresponding rank of the magic square.

```
n =  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19 20
r =  3  3  5  5  7  3  9   7  11   3  13   9  15   3  17  11  19  3
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is the rank of a magic square? The rank of the corresponding matrix? Also, I don't think there is anything like **the** magic square of size $n$. There are several essentially different magic squares of a given size (for large sizes at least), and the rank may depend... If you describe the construction of magic squares that lead to your table, then we would have a more definite question. It may, of course, well turn out that with even size we can never achieve a full rank, but that may also depend on the construction.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. There is probably an interesting question underlying your observations. The question just feels underspecified at the moment :-)

Comment: This seems to be the source:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/magic.html